# Apple don't send information about my app in email for admin users

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I have a developer account in apple, the bad thing is this that I can't access to the emails of this account. I have recently uploaded a build in xcode successfully but it apears on testflight for 1 min, then it disapear. When i searched every body said check your email there is the reason. Then I have added another apple id as admin but in this new account i didn't receive any email about my application, and still my app is not showing in testflight.

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here.  I also don't see why the [tag:applescript] tag was used.  If you can, update your question with a specific question.  I'm removing the erroneous tag for now, but if your question later on turns out to pertain to AppleScript, feel free to add the tag back in.

Comment: Hi @CJK, no matter that it is like question or no. Can you help me with this problem I am facing?